# Magento Meetup in Hyderabad,India

Tags: discussion

On Saturday 23rd of May Magento Meetup is going to held in [Hyderabad,India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyderabad)

> - [Offical Site](http://inmagento.com/)
> - [Facebook Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/408637975974488/)
> - [Facebook Event Link](https://www.facebook.com/events/890004144398449/)

Interested people in and around the city premises please attend the event and let's make it a Magento Fest :)

**Update about Event**

It went really good we have Q&A Hour just like a competition,we listed the uses,also discussed about Magneto 2 and we also promised to increase our community in our city and also in India by conducting more this kind of meetups.

The photos and other media stuff will be updated later please follow this [link](http://www.meetup.com/India-Magento-Meetup/) for updates.

[image]

[More Pics here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/408637975974488/424387001066252/?ref=notif&notif_t=group_activity)

Next MeetUp is at [Mumbai,Maharastra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumbai) [Join Here](http://inmagento.com/)

Comment: can any one share the experiance ?

Comment: Yes I also want to know how was the Meetup :-)

Comment: Please check my updated content @RajeevKTomy ,keyur shah :)

Comment: thanks for information @dh47